# Storing a list in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, list, database-design

I have a list of 60+ products, I want to store the products subscribed by a client in a MySQL table. What is the best way to do this? As of now I am storing products as JSON under products column, as it is easy to parse from different languages. Like this:

```
{"products": ["SM", "NDVI"]}
```

In this case the client has subscribed to 2 of our products. Another method I can think of is having a varchar the size of total products(60+) in the products column.
Example let's say there are 5 products (Just for the ease of explanation):

```
00000 ---> Original String
10010 ---> User has subscribed for product 1 and 4
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The standard relational SQL way to handle this problem would be to maintain *three* tables:

```
clients (id, name, ...)
products (id, name, ...)
client_products (client_id, product_id)   -- primary key is client_id, product_id
```

The third table above is called a *junction* table, because it exists to store relationships between clients and the the products to which they have subscribed.  For example, to use your sample data, `client_products` might have the following entries:

```
client_id | product_id
1         | 1
1         | 2
```

And in `products`:

```
id | name
1  | SM
2  | NDVI
```